# SQL query for aggregation multiple columns

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to write a query in Presto SQL.

The table:

| words | id1 | id2 | id2_like | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| baseball | 28 | 2756 | 1. | 6 |
| baseball | 28 | 3180. | 0. | 5 |
| baseball | 28. | 8161. | 0. | 17 |
| baseball | 11. | 1723 | 0. | 22 |
| baseball | 11. | 5329. | 1. | 29 |
| football. | 19. | 3210. | 1. | 2 |
| football. | 19. | 5519 | 0. | 18 |
| football. | 19. | 6257 | 1. | 3 |

`id2_like` depends on `id2` and it can only be 1 or 0.

I would like to get some aggregation results from the above table within one SQL query.

For each value in `words`, we need to get

1. Total number of `id2_like = 1`
2. Percentage of `id2_like` as 0 out of total `id2_like`
3. Number of `id1` where `id2_like = 0`
4. Average over `id1` the max rank of `id2_like = 0`
5. Average percentage of id2 as 0 over `id1` (in case some `id2_like = 1` and some are 0)

I know how to develop query for each one but I am not sure how to get all of them within one single SQL query.

Expected results:

```
words.   id1_cnt_for_id2_as_1  perc_id2_as_0  id1_cnt_for_id2_as_0_perc.   max_rank_id2_as_0   avg_perc_id2_as_0
baseball     2                     3/5        2                                (17+22)/2               (2/3+1/2)/2   
  
football.  2.                       2/3.     1.                             18                    1/3.
```

Comment: Please only tag the SQL product that you are using i.e. presto

Comment: Also show the resulting expected results table using the sample data

Comment: @xQbert, I have updated the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If  I understand correctly here is what you want, however I didn't understand what you want for number 5

```
select  words
    , sum(id1_cnt_for_id2_as_1) as id1_cnt_for_id2_as_1
    , sum(sum_perc_id2_as_0)* 100.0 /sum(cnt_perc_id2_as_0) as perc_id2_as_0
    , sum(id1_cnt_for_id2_as_0_perc) id1_cnt_for_id2_as_0_perc
    , avg(max_rank_id2_as_0) as max_rank_id2_as_0
    , avg(avg_perc_id2_as_0) as avg_perc_id2_as_0 
from (
select words
    , sum(id2_like) as id1_cnt_for_id2_as_1
    , sum(case when id2_like= 0 then 1 end) as sum_perc_id2_as_0
    , count(*)  as cnt_perc_id2_as_0
    , count(distinct case when id2_like =0 then id1 end) id1_cnt_for_id2_as_0_perc
    , sum(case when id2_like= 0 then rank end) as max_rank_id2_as_0
    , sum(case when id2_like= 0 then 1 end)* 100.0/count(*)  as avg_perc_id2_as_0
from data
group by words,id1
) t group by words
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a5f63951246feceaddf72de0a6b52826)*

Comment: @user3448011 see updated asnwer

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you to get some idea of what to do, tested in AWS Athena (pretty much like presto under the hood). Did not understood the fifth question.

```
SELECT 
        words, 
        item_1,  
        item_1 / CAST(size as decimal(10,4)) * 100 as item_2, 
        size - item_1 as item_3,
        max_rank as item_4
    FROM (
         SELECT 
              words, 
              SUM(id2_like) as item_1, 
              COUNT(*) as size,
              AVG(id1/CAST((SELECT MAX(rank) FROM tb WHERE id2_like = 0) as decimal(10,4))) as max_rank
         FROM tb 
         GROUP BY 1
         )
```